# How to serialize/unserialize an Array of Custom object in Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, serialization, kotlin

In my Kotlin Android project, I made a FileItem class which extends Serializable

```
class FileItem(<parameters>) : Serializable, Comparable<FileItem> {
```

So I needed to Serialize instances of this class into a Bundle

```
val arguments:Bundle = Bundle()
arguments.putSerializable("folders", folders as Serializable)
```

where folders has been declared as :

```
folders:Array<FileItem> (method parameter)
```

The serialization code above compile without any warning. Meanwhile, the problem comes when I need to unserialize folders items :

```
val arguments: Bundle? = getArguments()
if (arguments != null){
    foldersItems = arguments.getSerializable("folders") as Array<FileItem>
```

where foldersItems is declared as

```
var foldersItems: Array<FileItem>?
```

I get the following warning, that I can't manage to solve **without suppress_warning annotation** :

```
w: <Path to my class>: (78, 28): Unchecked cast: java.io.Serializable! to kotlin.Array<com.loloof64.android.chess_positions_archiver.main_file_explorer.FileItem>
```

This kind of code compiles in Java/Groovy without warning (folderItems is then a FileItem[]), so how can I modify the kotlin code for the compiler to be "satisfied" ?

I noticed [in official Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/index.html) that Kotlin Array does not extend Serializable and is not open for inheritance. Is it possible meanwhite to "add" it via a kind of extension method ?

Comment: As to the arrays serialization, they are serializable in Kotlin, too. This snippet shows it: https://gist.github.com/h0tk3y/bc892327ab239121e76df645d32d9832. I don't know why the reference doesn't state it, maybe it's because `Array<SomeType>` is compiled into Java's `SomeType[]`, which is surely serializable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, the cast is not unchecked, the compiler's warning is misleading.

This happens because in Kotlin arrays are represented by generic class `Array<T>`, and the compiler treats it as usual generic class with type parameters erased at runtime.

But on JVM [arrays have reified types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518556/arrays-are-reified-in-java), and when you cast `something as Array<SomeType>`, the generated bytecode really checks the type parameter to be `SomeType` as well as `something` being an `Array<*>`, which would only happen for any other generic class.

This example shows that the array cast is checked:

```
val a: Any = Array<Int>(1) { 0 }

val i = a as Array<Int>
val d = a as Array<Double> // gets checked and throws ClassCastException
```

The easiest solution is indeed to [`@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36221405/how-can-i-suppress-unchecked-cast-warnings), because actually there should not be any warning.

I filed an [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11948) describing the problem in Kotlin issue tracker.

Comment: Ok. Sorry for the duplicate, your link wasn't purposed when I was creating my discussion.

Comment: Maybe an easy question, but where would you put exactly the annotation in my example (where I try to retrieve the Serializable into the folders array) : I did not manage to suppress the warning. I tried foldersItems = @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST") arguments.getSerializable("folders") as Array<FileItem>

Comment: @loloof64 This should work: `foldersItems = @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST") (arguments.getSerializable("folders") as Array<FileItem>)`. Or just annotate the enclosing function.

Answer (score 1):

The cast here is unchecked because the compiler here can't ensure the *nullability* of array's generic type parameter.

Consider the following example:

```
fun castAsArrayOfString(param: Any) = param as Array<String>

castAsArrayOfString(arrayOf("a")) // is Array<String>, all ok

castAsArrayOfString(arrayOf("a", null)) // is Array<String>, but contains null
```

So the compiler warns you about potential type safety problems this cast could introduce.