# How to get a KClass of Array?

Tags: reflection, kotlin

I wrote the below code to get a KClass of `Array<*>`.

```
Array::class
```

However, this code has a compilation error.

> Kotlin: Array class literal requires a type argument, please specify one in angle brackets

Do you know the reason or solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On the JVM platform, [Kotlin `Array<T>` types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#arrays) are mapped to [Java arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html), which, unlike Java generic types, are not subject to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), they are [reified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518556/arrays-are-reified-in-java) instead.

It means, among other things, that arrays with different element types are represented by different classes, which have different `Class<T>` tokens, and these class tokens contain the information about the element type as well. There's no *generic* array type, but only array types for arrays with different element types.

Since *generic* `Array<T>` doesn't exist, you cannot use its reflection either, you can only get the runtime type information of array types with specified element types:

```
val c = Array<Int>::class // corresponds to Java Integer[] type
val d = Array<Array<String>>::class // corresponds to Java String[][]

val e = IntArray::class // corresponds to Java int[]
```

If you need to check whether an arbitrary class is an array type, you can do it with Java reflection:

```
val c = Array<Int>::class

println(c.java.isArray) // true
```